# Multiple files uploading not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

While ***uploading the multiple files in codeigniter i am getting error*** like this,

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in .../system\libraries\Upload.php

```
if(isset($_FILES['med_file']))
            {
                $config['upload_path'] = './medical_history_doc/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|doc|docx|pdf|txt';
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                $files = $_FILES;
                $cpt = count($_FILES['med_file']['name']);

                for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
                {
                    if($files['med_file']['name'][$i] !="")
                    {

                        $_FILES['med_file']['name']= $files['med_file']['name'][$i];
                        $_FILES['med_file']['type']= $files['med_file']['type'][$i];
                        $_FILES['med_file']['tmp_name']= $files['med_file']['tmp_name'][$i];

                        $attachment_name=$files['med_file']['name'][$i];
                        $path_info=pathinfo($attachment_name);
                        $file_extension=@$path_info['extension'];
                        $path_part_filename=$path_info['filename'];
                        $rename_file=str_replace(" ","",$path_part_filename).'_'.date('Ymdhis');

                        if(!empty($rename_file))
                        {

                            $_FILES['med_file']['name'] = $rename_file.'.'.$file_extension;
                            $medical_history_files[]=$rename_file.'.'.$file_extension;
                            if($this->upload->do_upload('med_file'))
                            {
                                $file_upload='true';

                            }
                            else if(!$this->upload->do_upload('med_file'))
                            {
                                $file_upload="fail";
                                $error= $this->upload->display_errors();

                                $this->session->set_flashdata('sucess', $error);
                            }
                          }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

and my **view** page code is like this.

```
<form method="post" name="medicalhistory" id="medicalhistory"
            enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="med_file" type="file" name="med_file[]" multiple>
</form>
```

Please help me how to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: change this `if ($this->upload->do_upload('med_file[]')) {` and try

Comment: @Saty. tried like that. not working

Comment: You missed action attribute in form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a couple of things here.. First of all, your HTML `form` should have the attribute `action` pointing to your controller method. Second, the `$_FILES` array should always contain  the following: `name, type, tmp_name, error, size`, however, in your loop you are only rebuilding with `name, type, tmp_name,` and you are forgetting the others. You are also renaming the file prior its being sent to the upload library. You should do this by setting it in the `config` array that is being sent to the library. I would redo you code in the following manner:

**Step 1:** Make sure the HTML form has the action attribute:

```
<form action="<?= base_url()?>controller/upload" ..
```

**Step 2:** Retrieve the files and unset the original $_FILES so that you can rebuild the array:

```
$uploaded_files = $_FILES['med_file'];
unset($_FILES);
```

**Step 3:** loop through the obtained files and rebuild the $_FILES array into a multidimensional array:

```
foreach ($uploaded_files as $desc => $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $k => $string) {
        $_FILES[$k][$desc] = $string;
    }
}
```

**Step 4:** Load the Upload library, and set your config options

```
$this->load->library('upload');
$config['upload_path'] = './medical_history_doc/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|doc|docx|pdf|txt';
```

**Step 5:** Loop through the new $_FILES array, rename you file and set the `config['filename']` to the new name. Initialize your upload, then run it:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $k => $file) {
    $path_info = pathinfo($file["name"]);
    $file_extension = $path_info['extension'];
    $path_part_filename = $path_info['filename'];
    $config['file_name'] = str_replace(" ", "", $path_part_filename) . '_' . date('Ymdhis') . '.' . $file_extension;

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload($k)) {
        $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
        var_dump($errors);
    } else {
        var_dump("success");
    }

}
```

---

**FINAL RESULT**:

**View**:

```
<form action="<?= base_url()?>controller/upload" method="post" id="medicalhistory" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="med_file" type="file" name="med_file[]" multiple>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function upload() {
    $uploaded_files = $_FILES['med_file'];
    unset($_FILES);

    foreach ($uploaded_files as $desc => $arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $k => $string) {
            $_FILES[$k][$desc] = $string;
        }
    }

    $this->load->library('upload');
    $config['upload_path'] = './medical_history_doc/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|doc|docx|pdf|txt';

    foreach ($_FILES as $k => $file) {
        $path_info = pathinfo($file["name"]);
        $file_extension = $path_info['extension'];
        $path_part_filename = $path_info['filename'];
        $config['file_name'] = str_replace(" ", "", $path_part_filename) . '_' . date('Ymdhis') . '.' . $file_extension;

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload($k)) {
            $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
            var_dump($errors);
        } else {
            var_dump("success");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @CodeGodie for well explanation. I understand your solutions and its working like a charm!. I given form action in my code. sorry i didnt update in post. I would like to know where i did mistake in my code

Comment: You're welcome. The mistakes are as I pointed out; the $_FILES being sent to the upload library were not set correctly, and the renaming was done prior sending the config which broke it.